# python not found but installed in environment variables

Tags: python, windows

I installed python-3.12.0-amd64 .exe for Windows 10. I restarted my computer and python is added in the environment variables.
[image: env variables]

When I type "python" or "py" via cmd, python starts
[image: py]

BUT when I type "py a.py" it gives the error "python not found".
[image]

I have my python file named "a.py" in the folder and I am sure I am in the right folder.

and as far as I know if I type "where python" it should give me the file path but it doesn't.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

When I type "py a.py" my a.py python file should run.

Answer (score 0):

Install it via the Microsoft Store.

Python 3.x on Windows 10 or above causes a lot of issues when installed from a binary from python.org.